# How do I add an arg to $@?

Tags: bash, zsh, posix, arguments

I like to be able to `... && add-arg 'something'`, and have 'something' be added to the positional arguments, kind of like an inverse `shift`.

I tried `... && set "$@ something"`, but this didn't work, though just doing `set "$@ something"` (without the condition) seemed to work correctly.

Comment: Hmm, the `&&` conditional shouldn't matter. What would matter is if you run `set` in a subshell or in a function. (And of course `set "$@ sth"` just appends to the last positional parameter, instead of adding a new one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh` specifically, in addition [to the standard `set -- "$@" ...` shown by @Kusalananda](/a/530904), the positional parameters are also available via the `$argv`  array (like in csh), so you can  also do:

```
argv+=arg             # append one argument to the end
argv+=(arg2 arg3)     # append several arguments
argv[1,0]=(arg1 arg2) # insert in front
argv[3,0]=(x)         # insert before the 3rd element
2+=(x)                # same as above (insert after the 2nd)
2+=x                  # append x to the second argument (not to confuse with
                      # the above).
argv[2,5]=(y)         # replace 4 elements 2 to 5 with one y argument
argv[3,-1]=()         # truncate
1=()                  # same as "shift"
```

Answer (score 9):

In any POSIX shell,

```
set -- "$@" "value"
```

would add `value` to the end of the list of positional parameters (it would actually replace the list with a new longer list), and

```
set -- "value" "$@"
```

would add it in the beginning (and would technically be the reverse of a `shift` as `shift` removes the first element).  This holds true for `zsh`.

The `--` is used to protect the following values from accidentally being interpreted as options, in case they start with `-`.

The special variable `$@` is almost exclusively used as `"$@"` as this would expand to the value of each positional parameter individually quoted.  The expression `"$@ somethingelse"` would expand to the list of individually quoted positional parameters, with `<space>somethingelse` appended to the last of them.

To use the values of the positional parameters as a *single string* delimited by spaces (or whatever the first character of `$IFS` may be), use `"$*"` (`"$* somethingelse"` is well defined as a single string).  This is however *not* what you want to do in this instance as it would collapse your list of values to one single value.

Comment: `"$@ somethingelse"` appends the string `<space>somethingelse` to the last positional parameter, and expands all of them as distinct fields. _"...if the parameter being expanded was embedded within a word, the first field shall be joined with the beginning part of the original word and the last field shall be joined with the end part of the original word."_ ([2.5.2 Special Parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02))

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for that reference, I've been wondering about for a while now. I'll update the answer.